# Ansible manage crontab not set by ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a few servers where some jobs in crontab were set manually, now i want to replace them with new jobs (delete the old and add the new jobs) using ansible, i tried to delete cron with `shell` and add a new one with `cron` :

```
 tasks:
        - name: "remove crontab"
          shell: crontab -r
```

Here i faced a pivilege escalation problem.

Is there any way to do this with `cron module` or to pass privilege escalation issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have sudo access, use `become`:

```
- name: "remove crontab"
  shell: crontab -r
  become: yes
```

Comment: i have `sudo`access, so i added `become: yes` i run playbook using `ansible-plabook backups.yml` i got `sudo: password is required` any idea ?

Comment: Setup passwordless sudo on target server or run `ansible-playbook` with `--ask-become-pass` switch.

Comment: Worth noting that `crontab -r` returns exit code 1 if there is no crontab for a user. `ignore_errors: yes` might be useful.